# Access Multiple Criteria Join Syntax Error

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I'm trying to create a multiple criteria join.

I have a Table A of sales and another Table B I created of criteria to help categorize the sales.  I want to use contains to check to see if any of the fields in Table A contains any of the strings in table B.

The error I'm getting is "Syntax error in FROM clause".  I know Access is very particular about join parentheses and hope someone can help.  The code is below.

thanks!

SELECT *
FROM (appended as A

LEFT JOIN Sheet1 as B

ON (UCASE(A.CUSTOMER_NAME) like B.[Customer Name]+'*')

AND
UCASE(A.SRC_NATIONAL_ACCOUNT_NAME) like B.[End Customer]+'*'

and
UCASE(A.JOB_NAME) like B.[Job Name]+'*'

and
UCASE(A.[Ship addressee]) like B.[Ship Addressee]+'*'))

Answer (score 1):

quit **AS** before alias table

```
SELECT * FROM (appended A
LEFT JOIN Sheet1 B
ON (UCASE(A.CUSTOMER_NAME) like B.[Customer Name]+'*')
AND UCASE(A.SRC_NATIONAL_ACCOUNT_NAME) like B.[End Customer]+'*'
and UCASE(A.JOB_NAME) like B.[Job Name]+'*'
and UCASE(A.[Ship addressee]) like B.[Ship Addressee]+'*'))
```